FCC/IC/RED Modular Approvals in Place
Here you can read:

FCC/IC/RED Modular Approvals in Place

I'm aware what "Modular Approvals" means, but what does "in Place" mean within this context?

Somewhat off-topic, but just a friendly reminder for any readers; Remember that even if FCC/IC/RED approvals exist for a radio module, that typically doesn't mean you can add them into any product of yours and consider yourself done regarding any radio related regulations, there's much more to it.

@Klas-Kenny, yes, I'm aware of that. Thanks for pointing it out anyway

It just means that they have supposedly tested this at a 3rd party test house, with some approved antenna(s). "In place" = everything is in order (supposedly).
However...

There's no FCC/CE markings visible on the product - which isn't required if there isn't any room,
But there is also no Declaration of Conformity available at their web site. It is required to be available somewhere, if only in paper form when you buy the product etc.

If one has gone through with all the testing, one usually wants to advertise that loud and proud. So before picking this product, you should contact them and ask for their Declaration of Conformity, just to confirm it is legit. For FCC/IC there should also be certification numbers from the tests.

Actually, on the item I have here on my desk there is the CE marking and an FCC ID. Anyway, I'm going to follow your hint!

@Mark All good then, probably!
